# add html edit button to quill in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, quill, html-editor

I would like to make a custom toolbar for my quill editor. Therefore I would like to add another button to the toolbar for converting the text I enter into html code. I have tried several methods but they didn't work out. Please help me with an idea.

What i have in component.html:

```html
 <quill-editor [styles]="{height: '200px'}" [modules]="editorModules" (onEditorChanged) = "changedEditor($event)"></quill-editor>
```

And here is what i have in component.ts:

editorText='';

```
      editorModules = {
        toolbar: [
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'], 

          [{align:''}, {align:'center'}, {align:'right'}, {align: 'justify'}],
          [{'indent': '-1'},{'indent': '+1'} ], 

          [{'size' : ['small', false, 'large', 'huge']}],

          ['color'], 
          ['link'], 
          [{'list': 'bullet'}, {'list': 'ordered'}], 
          ['image'] 
        ]
      }

changedEditor(event: EditorChangeContent | EditorChangeSelection) {
    console.log('editor got changed'); 
    this.editorText = event['editor']['root'];
}
```

Here is a photo of my current Text Editor:

[Text Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVsIA.png)

I would very much appreciate if you would try to help me, thank you.

Comment: Hello, Did you find a solution? thank you